# Verifying Cauchy-Riemann equations for $f(z) = \bar{z}^2/z$ at the origin

Tags: complex-analysis

We're given a two variable function as follows :

$$ f(z) = \begin{cases} 
      \dfrac{\bar{z}^{2}}{z} , & z\neq0 \\
      0\:\:\:, & z=0 \\ 
\end{cases} $$

We need to show that the Cauchy-Riemann equations are satisfied at the origin, that is, $z=0$.

We write : $z=x+iy$ and $\bar{z}=x-iy$.

Simplifying the function gives $f(x,y)$ as:

$$f(x,y) = \dfrac{(x^{3}-3xy^{2})+i(y^{3}-3x^{2}y)}{x^{2}+y^{2}}. $$

Thus, real part $u(x,y)=\dfrac{(x^{3}-3xy^{2})}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$, and imaginary part $v(x,y)=\dfrac{(y^{3}-3x^{2}y)}{x^{2}+y^{2}}$.

The partial derivatives came out as follows:

$$u_x =\dfrac{x^{4}+3y^{2}(2x^{2}-y^{2})}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}},$$
and 
$$v_y = \dfrac{y^{4}+3x^{2}(2y^{2}-x^{2})}{(x^{2}+y^{2})^{2}}.$$

But there values at origin are of indeterminate forms, how to show that $u_x = -v_y$ at $(0,0)$ ?

Kindly help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Compute $u'_x(0,0)$ (and the other derivatives) using the definition directly:
$$
u'_x(0,0) = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{u(h,0)-u(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{h^3}{h^2}}{h} = 1
$$
and similarly for the others.

Comment: How can we take $u(0,0) = 0$ ?

Comment: Never mind , got it. Thanks ! @mrf

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to compute $u_x$ etc. outside the origin, you just need to compute the partial derivatives of $f$ at the origin,

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{f(x+0i) - f(0)}{x} = \lim_{x\to 0}\frac{x-0}{x} = 1,$$

and

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0) = \lim_{y\to 0} \frac{f(0+iy) - f(0)}{y},$$

and see whether the Cauchy-Riemann equations

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}(0) = \frac{1}{i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}(0)$$

are satisfied.

Comment: sir, what if for some function $\frac{∂f}{∂x}(z_0)$ and $\frac{∂f}{∂y}(z_0)$ does not exists? then what to say? Cauchy Riemann equations are satisfied or Not? (I have function defined as $\frac{\bar{z}^{2}}{z^2}$ when $z≠0$ and $0$ when $z=0$ ) please sir help me...

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi The Cauchy-Riemann equations can only be satisfied at points where the partial derivatives exist. At points where one (or both) of the partial derivatives doesn't exist, one cannot even _state_ the Cauchy-Riemann equations.

Comment: Thank you so much sir...:-)